# Create a SharePoint 2010 BCS connection to Web Service with Visual Studio only

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, bcs

While I have been using SharePoint for quite some time I have not used BCS at all (except way back when I took some training).  What I am looking for are steps to create a BCS connector to an external content type.  The external data however can only be accessed through web services.  The other requirement is to do it without SharePoint designer.  We want it all packaged up in Visual Studio.  I have found documentation to do this in SharePoint Designer, but can't find any examples of building a content type off of a web service only in Visual Studio.

Thank you.

Comment: I just realized I forgot a key point. I must first authenticate to the web service provider before I can call the web services. This is why Designer is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fairly comprehensive 4-part series on MSDN that may be what you are looking for -
[Building WCF Web Services for SharePoint 2010 Business Connectivity Services (4-part series)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg318615%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

You may also want to consider the posts from the [Microsoft Business Connectivity Services Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bcs/) for more examples & tips.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input Supriyo.  I don't believe the first one will work for me as these are non WCF services (in fact they are created via Java web services).  I will take a look at the second link you provided though.  Thank you.

Comment: I just realized I forgot a key point. I must first authenticate to the web service provider before I can call the web services. This is why Designer is not an option.

Comment: You may have to explore using BCS with .NET assembly modules. The assembly would interface with the external Java web services and provide the results to the SP BCS.  Also look into wrapping WCF onto the web services. Check out this post regarding assembly and custom connectors to SP BCS (replace database source in example to java web service calls) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557349(v=office.14).aspx